# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to load this data from firebase:

```
Widget BlogList() {
return Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      blogSnapshot != null ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: blogSnapshot.docs.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return BlogTile(
            authorName: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['authorName'],
            title: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['title'],
            description: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['description'],
            imgUrl: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['imgUrl'],
          );
        },
      ): Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

but i am getting this error:

```
    Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                authorName: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['authorName'],
                                                         ^
```

pls have me out here with this error

Comment: Instead of `authorName: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data['authorName']` , try `authorName: (blogSnapshot.docs[index].data as Map)['authorName']` . It may work.

Comment: would `.data()['authorName']` work? Console output suggests `.data` is a function rather than a getter

Comment: none is working its not displaying

Comment: Have u tried: "blogSnapshot.docs[index]['authorName']"

Comment: error clearly says `data` if NOT a map, it’s Function, show full code

Comment: yes i have tried that...... this is what is saying Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return BlogTile(
            authorName: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data()['authorName'],
            title: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data()['title'],
            description: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data()['description'],
            imgUrl: blogSnapshot.docs[index].data()['imgUrl'],
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that somewhere in that chain (like data) is a function, and needs invoking by adding ().  Use your IDE to verify the type of data.

Comment: i did but is still not displaying